# Git checkout generates an error on --assume-unchanged files

Tags: git, git-index

After I run `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file` on a particular branch, I'm unable to switch branches using `git checkout`.

It throws the following error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> ```
>       path/to/file
> ```
>
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>
> Aborting

But both `git diff` & `git status` tells me there is no difference & there is nothing to commit/stash.

How do I switch out of the branch?

Is there a better alternative to `git update-index --assume-unchanged`  (other than `.gitignore`, because I don't want it to be ignored)? (Same as question 2 @ [git update-index --no-assume-unchanged doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755922/git-update-index-no-assume-unchanged-doesnt-work?rq=1))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some amount of use I now prefer `git update-index --skip-worktree` which is a much better alternative to the `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

Check out [*Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/556856) for further information.

I also am planning to check out the method specified in [this answer to *git assume unchanged vs skip worktree - ignoring a symbolic link*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6139470/556856), which seems to be more defensive approach.

Comment: Hi @Sujay, this still, however, doesn't allow you to checkout to another branch. Did you find a solution to branch-switching after skip-worktree or assume-unchanged?

Comment: Sorry @RutoCollins I wasn't able to figure that one out.
I generally prefer stashing and unstashing now to get out of that.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing today, and most of the answers I found, disappointingly, were similar to @Sujay's -- they didn't actually say how to get around the `git checkout` error.

Well, I found a solution that worked from [this page](https://newbedev.com/preserve-git-assume-unchanged-files-between-branch-checkouts) (couldn't figure out who the author was so that I could give credit):

> The solution that worked for me was to use --skip-worktree. However, like some above, I struggled with being able to switch between a ticketed branch and the main branch without git complaining even after I had set the --skip-worktree flag on the file whose changes I wanted to remain local.

...

> 1. `cp <local-only_file> ~/`
>
>    - copy file that has your local-only changes to somewhere safe on the filesystem
> 2. `git checkout <local-only_file>`
>
>    - in working tree, checkout file so that it matches master branch file
> 3. `git update-index --skip-worktree -- <local-only_file>`
> 4. `cp ~/<local-only_file> ./`
>
>    - copy file in question from safe location back into working tree
> 5. `git diff`
>
>    - no changes should be shown; if you push to the main repo, no changes in `<local-only_file>` are included in the push

The full solution began with `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>` before proceeding with the steps above.  After following these steps, I was able to switch branches.